# schedule pihole blacklist from text file of domains with crontab on raspberry pi

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to edit my crontab to make a scheduled block of specific domains for my pi hole configuration.

my setup is that I've got a file: 'blocklist.txt' which contains a list of domains like:

```
instagram.com
facebook.com
newssite.com
```

and I'm using the following to get that to work with xargs. I've taken the normal version and converted it to absolute paths here so that it will work in cron. I'm also attempting to write out to a file at /home/pi/cron.log which I made just to capture the output and see what's going on. nothing updates there either.

`46 17 * * * /usr/bin/xargs -a /home/pi/blocklist.txt /usr/local/bin/pihole --wild &>/home/pi/cron.log`

this works totally fine when running in my normal shell and updates the log, etc... but does not work when I try to schedule a cron job for it a few minutes out.

Maybe I'm missing something with my paths or with scheduling?

I already converted my timezone in raspi-config to my timezone.

Comment: update, the following is working for updating every 3 minutes as a test: 

```*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/xargs -a /home/pi/blocklist.txt /usr/local/bin/pihole --wild &>/home/pi/cron.log```

Comment: I've been trying to do this in UTC time I thought that might be the issue, but I set the schedule for a few minutes from now and I'm still getting nothing :(

Comment: ok so my time settings are: ```Local time: Tue 2020-08-25 20:53:16 CDT
           Universal time: Wed 2020-08-26 01:53:16 UTC``` and the cron job is fining at ```53 02 * * *``` for this, No idea where it's getting that time from?

Comment: no idea why, but this morning, things seem to be working with these settings, maybe I just needed time for the system to get moved over to the new timezone or something?

 ```0 5 * * * /usr/bin/xargs -a /home/pi/blocklist.txt /usr/local/bin/pihole --wild &>/home/pi/cron.log```
 and 
```30 9 * * * /usr/bin/xargs -a /home/pi/blocklist.txt /usr/local/bin/pihole --wild -d &>/home/pi/cron.log```

Answer (score 0):

My solution does not currently read from a file, but it's very close to what you are looking for. Here's a [blog post with lots of details](http://mikebian.co/blocking-ads-monitoring-external-drives-with-raspberry-pi/), but here are the core snippets:

block.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
blockDomains=(facebook.com www.facebook.com pinterest.com www.pinterest.com)

for domain in ${blockDomains[@]}; do
  pihole -b $domain
done
```

allow.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
blockDomains=(facebook.com www.facebook.com pinterest.com www.pinterest.com)

for domain in ${blockDomains[@]}; do
  pihole -b -d $domain
done
```

Allow execution on these scripts:

```sh
chmod +x /home/pi/Documents/block.sh
chmod +x /home/pi/Documents/allow.sh
```

Block after 9pm, allow after 6am. crontab -e:

```
0 21 * * * bash -l -c '/home/pi/Documents/block.sh' | logger -p cron.info
0 6 * * * bash -l -c '/home/pi/Documents/allow.sh' | logger -p cron.info
```